# MATLAB - destroy listener after force quit ctrl+c

Tags: matlab, listener

I am working on a Matlab script for temperature acquisition with an NI device. I use a listener to run a callback function for refreshing my chart. When I do Ctrl+C, the main script stops with the following error: "Undefined function 'wait' for input arguments of type 'event.listener'.". The problem is that the listener still trigger events, so my chart keeps refreshing.

I've tried to catch it with a try/catch and I used the onCleanup function to delete the listener, but without success.

Can someone give me some advices please? :)

EDIT : here is the code

```
s = daq.createSession('ni'); 
s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod1', 0, 'Thermocouple'); 
s.Rate = 7; 
s.DurationInSeconds = 5;
s.Channels.ThermocoupleType = 'T';
s.Channels.Units = 'Celsius';

lh = addlistener(s,'DataAvailable',@plotData);
ocu = onCleanup(@() delete(lh)); 

s.startBackground();
try
    wait(s);
catch
    delete(lh);
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a better way to end your script... thanks for adding the actual question to your question!

Comment: The "proper" way to do is to use the stop button on my GUI, but sometimes I use Ctrl+C for debugging purposes (or simply just because I forgot to use the Stop button), and I need to wait until the end of the acquisition time because I can't delete the listener...

Comment: You may need to show us some code - how are you creating the listener, where are you storing it, how are you using try/catch/onCleanup etc. It's difficult to tell what might be the issue otherwise.

Comment: I've added the code. The callback just draws a chart.

Answer (score 0):

To allow your code to respond gracefully to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, try attaching a callback to the [`ErrorOccurred` event](https://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/erroroccurred.html) that [stops the session](https://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/stop_session.html):

```
...

errListener = addlistener(s, 'ErrorOccurred', @(~, ~) stop(s));

s.startBackground();
wait(s);
```

Comment: I've tried, and still the same problem. Here is the error: "Operation terminated by user during daq.Session/doWait (line 2827)".

Comment: @ardayigit: Are `DataAvailable` events still being fired after the error? Does the listener get destroyed?

Comment: The listener is not destroyed before the end of the time definied by "s.DurationInSeconds", so DataAvailable events are still being fired.

Comment: @ardayigit: Third time's the charm?

Comment: Still not :/ Same problem!